# Pushing JQuery promises into array executes deferred functions Asynchronously

Tags: jquery, arrays, asynchronous, promise, deferred

I'm trying to understand Javascript deferred functions. I have come up with an issue in a mobile application I'm developing with JQuery Mobile.

I have made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2TFKy/2/) with the example but I paste here the code for clarity.

```
var promises = [];

function out() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += args.join(" ") + "\n";
}

function testDeferred(a) {
    return $.Deferred(function (d) {
        if (a == 1) {
            d.resolve(a);
        } else {
            d.reject(a);
        }
    });
}

function testDeferred2(a) {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();

    if (a == 1) {
        deferred.resolve(a);
    } else {
        deferred.reject(a);
    }
    return deferred.promise();
}


promises.push(testDeferred(1));
promises.push(testDeferred2(1));

out(promises[0].state());
out(promises[1].state());

$.when.apply($, promises)
    .done(function () {
    out("Done");
});
```

What I intend:

1. Push both **testDeferred** and **testDeferred2** promises into the array "promises", forcing them to resolve.
2. Execute both using **$.when.apply.**

What I achieve is both functions being executed at the very moment I push them. The prove is their state after pushing them becomes "resolved".

I removed the ".promise()" ending in **testDeferred** on purpose to test if I should return a promise or just the deferred. Same thing happened.

Please, I need some help here... Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused. Maybe it's because you're confused. :) So far what you have described is exactly what should have happened. When you create the deferred object, you're immediately resolving it, therefore they are in a resolved or rejected state sitting in the array, waiting for you to pass to .when. Passing the whole deferred object or just the promise as a return value doesn't make a difference, as both promise object and deferred objects have a promise method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> both functions being executed at the very moment I push them

Yes, that's what you are doing here:

```
promises.push(testDeferred(1));
promises.push(testDeferred2(1));
```

You are calling the functions, which will return resolved promises (or deferreds, for that matter). However, you will need to distinguish between *executing* the function, and *resolving* the promises.

Your code does that synchronously, which is rather unusual, normally you'd expect to execute the functions immediately and resolve the returned promise later:
When writing asynchronous code (imagine a `setTimeout` or a `$.ajax` in the test functions), then you are calling them immediately, which *starts* the asynchronous tasks right away, but get *pending* promise for their results.

```
function testDeferredDelay(a, ms) {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() { // happens now
        deferred.resolve(a); // happens later
    }, ms);
    return deferred.promise(); // happens now
}

promises.push(testDeferredDelay(1, 50));
promises.push(testDeferredDelay(2, 100));

out(promises[0].state()); // pending
out(promises[1].state()); // pending

$.when.apply($, promises) // happens now
.done(function () {
    out("Done"); // happens later
});
```

([updated demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2TFKy/3/))